# Amazon Athena partitioning query error "no viable alternative"

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I'm trying to make a partitioned data table in Amazon Athena, so that I can analyze the contents of a bucket containing S3 access logs. I've followed the instructions almost exactly as they are written in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html), just substituting my own info. However, I keep getting the error `line 1:8: no viable alternative at input 'create external' (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: 847e3d9c-8d3c-4810-a98c-8527270f8dd8).` Here's what I'm inputting:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE access_data (
         `Date` DATE,
         Time STRING,
         Location STRING,
         Bytes INT,
         RequestIP STRING,
         Host STRING,
         Uri STRING,
         Status INT,
         Referrer STRING,
         os STRING,
         Browser STRING,
         BrowserVersion STRING 
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
WITH serdeproperties ( 'paths'='`Date`,Time, Uri' )
PARTITIONED BY (dt DATE) STORED AS parquet LOCATION 's3://[source bucket]/';
```

I've looked at other [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912086/amazon-athena-no-viable-alternative-at-input) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59930025/unable-to-create-table-in-amazon-athena) on here but I don't have a hyphenated table name, no trailing commas, no unbalanced back ticks or missing parentheses, etc... so I really don't know what's wrong. Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that these two lines are conflicting with each other:

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe' WITH serdeproperties ...
```

and

```
STORED AS parquet
```

Removing one of them allows the table creation to proceed.

Parquet does not store data in JSON format.